# Upgrading / Changing / Moving Windows 10 License

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, license, windows-10-pro

I've just bought a Windows 10 Pro License because I want to use that on my main PC which currently has Windows 10 Home on it for the extra features.

I've upgraded most things over the years so pretty much by buying a motherboard and hard drive, I can have another, fully working PC.

What I want to do is remove the Home license from my existing PC, upgrade to Pro then have the Home license on the "new" computer.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: If the machine came with windows 10 then you cannot move the licence. Only full "retail" licences are transferrable.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to do is remove the Home license from my existing PC,
> upgrade to Pro then have the Home license on the "new" computer.

The majority of Home licenses are OEM licenses (that is, pre-installed on the computer). These cannot be used on another computer.

So your Home License was just replaced by the Pro license and the Home license is gone.

Most system builder licenses are also OEM. If, somehow, the Home license was Retail and separate from the computer, you need to obtain the license key from the supplier and then you can re-use it.

Comment: The PC I have is a custom build, not from a manufacturer so I bought Windows 10 from the same place I got the hardware.

Comment: It is still likely the supplier provided you an OEM license. If that is the case, it cannot be moved. You need to check with the supplier.